# Hh: mm: SS to milliseconds

Tags: php, datetime, milliseconds

I want to convert time (hh:mm:ss) into milliseconds. Then how can I do that?

Ex: 
Time is: 00:00:11

Note: I need a code in PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "00:00:11";
$time   = explode(":", $string);

$hour   = $time[0] * 60 * 60 * 1000;
$minute = $time[1] * 60 * 1000;
$sec    = $time[2] * 1000;

$result = $hour + $minute + $sec;

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = '11:22:33';    
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
$miliseconds = $seconds * 1000;

echo $seconds ."\n" . $miliseconds;
```

output:
40953
40953000

Comment: I think OP wants milliseconds not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Date to time conversion will be like as follows

```
    $Given_date   = date('H:i:s');

    $hour         = date('H',strtotime($Given_date));
    $minute       = date('i',strtotime($Given_date));
    $seconds      = date('s',strtotime($Given_date));

    $sec_to_milli = $seconds * 1000;            //seconds to milliseconds
    $min_to_milli = $minute * 60 * 1000;        //minutes to milliseconds
    $hrs_to_milli = $hour * 60 * 60 * 1000;     //hours to milliseconds

    $milliseconds = $hrs_to_milli + $min_to_milli + $sec_to_milli;

    echo $milliseconds;
```